# send an circle object through socket

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have a code that is the ball motion with mouse control

ballFrame :

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class BallFrame extends Application {

    private Pane canvas;

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {

        canvas = new Pane();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(canvas, 800, 600);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Game");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        addCircle(100, 100, Color.BLUE);


        scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {         
            @Override         
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {  
                if (event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY) {
                    if (!(canvas.getChildren().isEmpty())) {
                        canvas.getChildren().remove(0);
                    }   
                }
                else {
                    int red = (int)(Math.random()*256);
                    int green = (int)(Math.random()*256);
                    int blue = (int)(Math.random()*256);
                    int x = (int)(Math.random()*801);
                    int y = (int)(Math.random()*601);
                    addCircle(x, y, Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
                }
            }     
        }); 

    }

    private void addCircle(double x, double y, Color color) {
        Circle circle = new Circle(15, color);
        circle.relocate(x, y);

        canvas.getChildren().addAll(circle);


        final Timeline loop = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(10), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            double deltaX = 3;
            double deltaY = 3;


            @Override
            public void handle(final ActionEvent t) {
                circle.setLayoutX(circle.getLayoutX() + deltaX);
                circle.setLayoutY(circle.getLayoutY() + deltaY);

                final Bounds bounds = canvas.getBoundsInLocal();
                final boolean atRightBorder = circle.getLayoutX() >= (bounds.getMaxX() - circle.getRadius());
                final boolean atLeftBorder = circle.getLayoutX() <= (bounds.getMinX() + circle.getRadius());
                final boolean atBottomBorder = circle.getLayoutY() >= (bounds.getMaxY() - circle.getRadius());
                final boolean atTopBorder = circle.getLayoutY() <= (bounds.getMinY() + circle.getRadius());

                if (atRightBorder || atLeftBorder) {
                    deltaX *= -1;
                }
                if (atBottomBorder || atTopBorder) {
                    deltaY *= -1;
                }
            }
        }));

        loop.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        loop.play();

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch(args);
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

That is extends to Application.
I want to crate 2 windows of the ball Frame, one is **server socket** and other is **client socket**.
I want to send balls from one window if it hit to right border to other window from right window and work like this both way.

I have no idea to do this

I have try to write code with  server socket and client like this but no idea to do anything.

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {

    public ServerSocket servsock;

    ServerThread(int port) throws IOException {
        servsock = new ServerSocket(port);
        servsock.setSoTimeout(30000);
    }

    public void gui() {

        }


    public void run() { 
        gui();
        while(true) { 
            try { 
                System.out.println("SERVER: waiting for connection on " + servsock.getLocalPort()); 
                Socket server = servsock.accept(); 
                System.out.println("SERVER: Client accepted: " + server);
                System.out.println("SERVER: connect to "+server.getRemoteSocketAddress()); 

                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(server.getInputStream()); 
                String text = in.readUTF();
                System.out.println("SERVER: get \"" + text + "\""); 


                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(server.getOutputStream()); 
                out.writeUTF(text); 

                server.close(); 
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                    System.out.println(e.toString()); 
                    try {
                        servsock.close();    
                        System.out.println("Bye bye"); 
                        break; 
                        } catch (IOException e1) { 
                            e1.printStackTrace(); 
                            } 
                    }   
            }  
        }

}
```

Client:

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread {
    Socket client;


    final String url; 
    final int port;


    public ClientThread(String ip, int port) { 
        this.url = ip; 
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void gui() {

        }

    public void run() {
        gui();
        display.append("Connecting to " + url + " on port " + port +"\n"); 
        send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent o) {
                try {
                    /* CONNECT */
                    client = new Socket(url, port);
                    display.append("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress() +"\n"); 
                    /* SEND */
                    OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream(); 
                    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer); 
                    out.writeUTF(input.getText());

                    /* READ */
                    InputStream inFromServer = client.getInputStream(); 
                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(inFromServer); 
                    display.append("Server says: " + in.readUTF() +"\n");


                    client.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                input.setText("");
            }               
        }); 

        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String serverName = "127.0.0.1"; 
        int port = 15788;

        ServerThread t = new ServerThread(port);
        t.start();
        Thread client = new ClientThread(serverName,port);  
        client.start();
        }

}
```

Comment: Short answer is, don't.  Send the data which would be required to build a new circle on the other side, maybe in json or xml (or some other simple format)

Comment: I'd advise you read the documentation on `Serializable`

Comment: can you guide some coding to combine application, server Socket and Client Socket

Comment: @ControlAltDel However, `Circle` does not implement `Serializable`, so it's not clear that would help.